# Setting up MingW and Code::Blocks in Windows 8 64 bit

Tags: c++, codeblocks, mingw-w64

I am trying to setup **MingW** and **Code::Blocks** on my *Windows 8 64 bit* laptop, and I'm facing some problem while building a `main.cpp` file. These are the versions that I have installed:

- [x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.7.4-release-win64_rubenvb.7z](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/gcc-4.7-release/) for *MingW* (4th one in that list), and
- [codeblocks-12.11-setup.exe](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26) for *Code::Blocks*.

I've set the path to `mingw64\bin` in the environment variable. Also, in the Code::Blocks compiler settings, I have set path for all *ToolChain Executables*. There are two *gcc* in the *MingW* bin path. One is - `gcc.exe` and other is - `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe`. Same for *C++ Compiler*, *Linker for static and dynamic libs*. Now when I try to build a simple *Hello World* file, it shows some errors:

```
obj\Debug\main.o -- In function swscanf  

c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.3\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wchar.h -- undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'

obj\Debug\main.o -- In function `wscanf':

c:\mingw\mingw64\bin\..\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.3\..\..\..\..\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wchar.h -- undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_sj0'
```

Similarly there are many errors and undefined references for - `fwprintf`, `wprintf`, `std:cout`, etc..

I'm sure there is some configuration problem, but I cannot find out what's the issue. Can any one take a look at the problem.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't require 64 bit support, consider downloading "codeblocks-12.11mingw-setup.exe"
It packs its own 32 bit mingw and has everything preconfigured for you.
Otherwise, if you still need to compile amd64 apps:-
Assuming you extracted to D:\Mingw64, under the "Tool Chain Executables" tab, set the "Compiler's Installation Directory" to "D:\Mingw64\bin", Then click auto-detect to check whether code::blocks likes what it finds.

If everythings Ok, make sure the rest of the fields are as follows:-

```
C compiler: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
C++ compiler: x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
Linker for dynamic libs: x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe
Linker for static libs: x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar.exe
Debugger: GDB/CDB Debugger... 
Ressource compiler: x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres.exe
Make program: mingw32-make.exe
```

Click on the "Additional Paths" tab and enter the following line:- (the path is correct for ver 4.7.4,the one you downloaded. It ends with 4.7.3)

```
D:\Mingw64\libexec\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.3\
```

Click on the "Search directories" tab to the imediate left "Toolchain Executables"
Add the following paths:-

```
D:\Mingw64\include
D:\Mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include
D:\Mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\c++\4.7.3
D:\Mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\c++\4.7.3\backward
D:\Mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\c++\4.7.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32
D:\Mingw64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.7.3\include
```

Click on the "linker" tab and add the following paths:-

```
D:\Mingw64\Lib 
D:\Mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib
```

And finally click on the "Compiler Settings tab", Click on "Other options" and add:-

```
-m64
```

One last thing-> remember to save those settings to disk! 
If it crashes while you test this new config, you might wish you had!
Do this (I think) either by "File->Save Everything" or restarting code::blocks ...**without another instance running**.

### Try compiling something then share the outcome

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did the changes for mingw64, but the same problem persists. Also, I didn't find all the paths you mentioned there. First, `Linker for dynamic libs:` was set to : `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe`. And the one for `static libs` was set to: `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ar.exe`. Also, `Resource Compiler` was set to just: `windres.exe`. Then in **Search Directory**, I didn't find the paths - 3, 4, ad 5th. Those including `C++`. Rest all the settings I did. but the same error was coming. As far as your frst option is concerned, I will try that too.

Comment: Oh dear :) Thank you so so much. Everything's working fine now. I changed the dynamic lib as you mentioned, and for static libs, I just set it to `ar.exe`. As I didn't have `g++-ar.exe`. And for C++, the path I added was directly inside the first `include` directory, which I used. And now, I'm seeing the output. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

Peace! Dear brother, I think you need this:

(1)
   std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;

You need to put "std::function_name" whenever you are using a predefined function from iostream.h, because this is you way access it in GCC, which Code::Blocks uses.

(2) Try it compiling by omitting "using namespace std;" from your code.
Because I've compiled C and C++ code many times in Code::Blocks on 32-bit Windows XP, and it did!

(3) Make sure the path is set to the directory "mingw\bin".

(4) Ensure if you have 64-bit MinGW installed and path set to its "bin" directory (if you want to compile for 64-bit). It will compile for 64-bit by default.

(5) Try the flags/arguments "-m32" and "-m64" for compiling for 32- and 64-big respectively.