# codeblocks permission denied

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks

I can't seem to get my C++ project working in CodeBlocks.

The errors I'm receiving are after trying to compile:

```
cannot find -lmingw
cannot find -lSDL2main
cannot find C:\C++Libraries\MingW\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\64: Permission denied.
```

Comment: looks like the user which compiles this program doesn't have enough permissions. try running it with full privilege.

Comment: @dreamer I ran CB as admin and still got the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your errors, I see you are trying to include SDL2. 
Are you able to compile programs without SDL2?

If not, then I'm guessing your compiler isn't setup properly, in which case this link might help you:
 [Setting up codeblocks & mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716454/setting-up-mingw-and-codeblocks-in-windows-8-64-bit)

If you have codeblocks and mingw (32 or 64) working and are struggling with including SDL2, then this might help you:
 [Setting up codeblocks & SDL2](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/codeblocks/index.php)

If you are 100% sure that both are setup correctly and you still get the exact same error, then I'm assuming something is wrong with file permissions, but I think it's one of the first two.